# How to insert elements from a file to an array recursively? -java-

Tags: java, recursion

I've been trying to figure this one out for a little while now and can't really find a solution. What I need to do is insert elements from a file into an array *recursively*. I realize that this can be done a lot easier with just a loop, but since this is homework, it has to be done recursively. I would just like a hint in the right direction. Im having a lot of trouble understanding recursion, so any help would be nice. The part that really confuses me is how to actually get the elements into the array. Here is what I have so far:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;


public class Recursion{

 public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{

  int i= 0;
  int findInts = 0;
 // reading file
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("heap.dat"));
  // finding ints in file
   while(scan.hasNextInt()){
      findInts = scan.nextInt();
       array(findInts);

  }

 }

 public static void array (int findInts) throws FileNotFoundException{
  int[] numbers = new int[1000]; // my array must have 1000 elements

   if(findInts == 0){
   System.out.println();
   }
   else{
   // Im really not sure what to do here
   // this gives me the infinite recursion error
   array(findInts);

   }


 }
```

Comment: Let me tell you something, this is not how recursive function works. Do not call the function in a loop from main. The function must call itself at some conditions.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was wrong, like I said Im really confused about the recursion thing.

Comment: You wouldn't use a while loop in main. That's the purpose of the recursion. Here's a tip for starting off: Your base case in the recursive method would check if `scan.hasNext() == false`

Comment: okay, that makes sense. But what would I put in my parameter ?

Comment: Did your assignment say specifically that the array will be size 1000?

Comment: Let the function take a `Scanner` object and an `int` as parameter. Define `int[] numbers` outside the function (inside the class as static). Call the function in main with `array(numbers, 0)`. The function must add the `nextInt()` to the numbers[i] (if it is not 0), and if `hasNextInt()` let it call itself with `array(numbers, i+1)`.

Comment: Yeah it did, the second part of the assignment wants us to sort the array, and get rid of the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Any recursion solution needs a base case to decide when to terminate the recursion. If this is missing, you will get infinite recursion. Here's an example pertaining to your case:

```
void addToArray(Scanner scan, int[] numbers, int index){
    if (scan.hasNextInt()){
        addToArray(scan, numbers, index++); //recursive case
    } else {
        return; //stop recursion
    }
}
```

Note I have deliberately left out the part where you need to add the number to the array. Since this is a homework, I'll let you figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to name your recursive method something besides "array". A function should hint at what it does. In this case "recursiveInsert" is a good bet. Also, declare your array outside the method.

I would also add that recursion has a "base case" where you actually perform an operation (returning a value, or in this case inserting a new number) and an "inductive step" where you call the function again with new arguments (remember, must always use the same types.

For your case, it looks like you are going to have a sorted array. You need an ALGORITHM to insert these elements in a sorted order. An algorithm is just an approach to solving your problem.

Here is a proposed algorithm (it will have fast runtime in order of log(N)):
Look up "binary search" [BINARY SEARCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
Basically, you check the middle of the list (length / 2). If it is bigger, check the lower-half of the list again and restrict the start and end indices, check the upper-half if it is smaller.

You will **HAVE** to change the signature of your method to take in a start and finish index.

Here's some code to get you started...

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Recursion{

public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{

  int i= 0;
  int findInts = 0;
  int [] array = new int[1000]//DECALRE YOUR ARRAY OUTSIDE METHOD 
 // reading file
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("heap.dat"));
  // finding ints in file
   while(scan.hasNextInt()){
      findInts = scan.nextInt();
       Recursive(findInts, 0, 1000, array);

  }

 }

//insertMe is the num to insert, start and end are the indices
//note that the array is passed to the method
 public static void recursiveInsert(int insertMe, int start, int end, int[] array) throws FileNotFoundException{
   //BASE CASE
   if(start <= end - 1) {
   //insert the value at the index by copying the lower and upper halves into other arrays
   //and "move" the upper values over to make space.
   }
   //check the index to see if it fits
   if(array[end / 2] > InsertMe) { //check the middle point
      recursiveInsert(insertMe, start, end / 2, array); //result is that the middle point was greater
   }                                              //so, recursively try again in lower-half

 //DO OTHER CODE THINGS HERE

 }
```

Comment: Please note, there are MUCH easier methods to use if you just need an arbitrary demonstration of recursion.

Here's another algorithm:
1) check the first element against the new value to insert
2) if it is smaller, check the rest of the list until you get one that is bigger.
3) once you have a >= value, insert at the previous index
4) (make a helper method to insert at a given index in the array)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! However, in the assignment, I was supposed to sort it in a separate method. I will use this advice for that method. I did end up solving the issue though!